# What was the dían type of old Irish verses?

Tags: online-resources, poetry, celtic, irish

Composing this type of poetic meter  was mentioned as [a skill obtained through the first year of education](https://www.ucc.ie/celt/published/G502003.html) of filídh (old Irish poets) at foclóc rank.

Are there any reliable online resourses regarding meters and genres of the Old Celtic poetry?